# Remember Me Bug

Tags: remember-me

I am using ExpressionEngine 2.7.2

I have a remember input box in my login form.

However, even if it is unchecked, I still login in immmediately to my site even if I closed the browser.

How is this fixed?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a bug.

The users CP session won't clear when you close the browser... it will clear when the session expires (which I think by default is 1 hour or 3600 seconds).

You can make this longer or shorter by setting "[**cp_session_ttl**](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/general/hidden_configuration_variables.html#cp-session-ttl)" in your config.php file:

```
$config['cp_session_ttl'] = 3600;
```

The number is in seconds.